# Symfony2 Symblog tutorial swift mail not getting email icon in developer bar

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

i am following this tutorial:

```
http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/docs/validators-and-forms.html
```

at the swift mailer part i am not getting the envelope icon in the developer bar. i am following the tutorial on my dev box so it wont send the actual email therefore i must get the  envelope?

here my  app/config/parameters.ini:

```
mailer_transport  = "gmail"
mailer_encryption = "ssl"
mailer_auth_mode =  "login"
mailer_host       = "smtp.gmail.com"
mailer_user       = "myemail@host.net"
mailer_password   = "mypassword"
```

then i have src/Blogger/BlogBundle/Controller/PageController.php:

```
public function contactAction()
{
   #return $this->render('BloggerBlogBundle:Page:contact.html.twig');
   $enquiry = new Enquiry();
   $form = $this->createForm(new EnquiryType(), $enquiry);

   $request = $this->getRequest();
   if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
   {
       $form->bindRequest($request);

       if ($form->isValid())
       {
         // Perform some action, such as sending an email
         $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject('Contact enquiry from symblog')
        ->setFrom('enquiries@symblog.co.uk')
        ->setTo($this->container->getParameter('blogger_blog.emails.contact_email'))
        ->setBody($this->renderView('BloggerBlogBundle:Page:contactEmail.txt.twig', array('enquiry' => $enquiry)));
        $this->get('mailer')->send($message);

        $this->get('session')->setFlash('blogger-notice', 'Your contact enquiry was successfully sent. Thank you!');


         // Redirect - This is important to prevent users re-posting
         // the form if they refresh the page
         return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('BloggerBlogBundle_contact'));
       }
    }


return $this->render('BloggerBlogBundle:Page:contact.html.twig', array(
    'form' => $form->createView()
));
```

after this i have everything like they have it,what am i missing?
please help?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't see the email icon because there is no email sent in the current request.

Actually, you're redirecting the user after sending the email so the request you see in the debug toolbar is the one after the one in which you send the email.

If you want to see the sent email, you have to go in the profiler history:

1. Go to the profiler (click one of the links in the bar)
2. Let the search form of the left sidebar empty and click its "search" button: you will get the 10 last requests
3. Pick the request corresponding to the one sending the email
4. You can now examine this request and the sent email should be available

Comment: thank you found it it shows stuff under Request POST Parameters and also Request Content..the values from the input boxes, but no where anything about mail sent?